# Visual Studio Online build error about NuGet client version (v3.0 or above required)

Tags: msbuild, nuget, tfsbuild, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to setup a CI build using Visual Studio Online but I am getting the following error about the NuGet client:

> The 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.

Solution builds and deploys fine directly from my Visual Studio 2015 itself but I am unable to get it to build in VSO. Does anyone if NuGet 3.x is installed on hosted build controllers or if I can supply my own copy along with my solution?

Comment: NuGet 2.8.6 is currently installed on the hosted build machines.  there were some major compatibility issues with NuGet 3 that needed to be addressed before we felt comfortable putting it into production.  New images will be rolling out with the updated bits over the next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to guess by the question what build tasks are used. If you use VSBuild/MSBuild, it is only possible to turn "Restore NuGet packages" on, but there's no influence on the NuGet version.

However, if you turn this checkbox off, and instead add another build task called NuGet Installer before the main build step, you'll be able to provide a custom path to NuGet.exe. In the case of hosted build agent, the most obvious option is to commit required version of NuGet.exe to the repo, and then reference it from the build step:

[image]

Sounds like a hack, but it might work in your case.